# What does the Rebel Alliance logo represent?

Tags: star-wars

This insignia is pretty common and recognizeable, but I'm not sure I have any idea what it represents. It looks sort of like the shape of a ship, but the Rebellion doesn't have any ships of this shape that I can recall.

[image: Rebel Alliance insignia]

So, what is it?

Comment: It represents the Rebel Alliance.

Comment: It's a Ferengi ship. Duh.

Comment: @iMerchant holy crap!

Comment: Or they just enjoyed watching Battlestar Galactica: http://img02.deviantart.net/1e3d/i/2011/110/1/2/battlestar_galactica_seal_by_viperaviator-d3efxyx.png

Comment: It represents badges on this site. SFF.SE is so well-known that the rebels took our symbol as their own.

Comment: I think before the prequels it was supposed to be the insignia of the Old Republic.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**In Disney Canon its origin is currently unconfirmed. But it's likely based on Sabine Wren's personal *Starbird* graffiti tag and/or the Jedi Crest.**

[image: logos]

In *Star Wars: Rebels,* Mandalorian weapons expert and painter [Sabine Wren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sabine_Wren) uses a stylized [Starbird](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starbird) (based on a mythological bird similar to the Phoenix, which can never die and renews itself in a nova) to tag Imperial ships and propaganda on Lothal.

[image]

Sabine later joins the similarly-named Phoenix cell lead by Commander Jun Sato, part of the fledgeling Rebel Alliance lead by Bail Organa and

> Ashoka Tano

However, by Season 2 **the show hasn't reached the point in history where the familiar crest comes into general Rebel use, but the design of Sabine's Starbird is clearly intended as an origin of the cleaner crest we know so well.**

The visually-similar [Jedi Crest](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Order) obviously predates Sabine's logo, and was worn by Jedi generals on the shoulders of their armor during the Clone Wars.

[image]

**We can therefore speculate that the final Rebel design may be a combination of these two - evoking both the rebirth and rebellious spirit of Sabine's Starbird, and the history and hope of the Jedi Order.**

(The Legends canon explanation is based on the Marek Family Crest, but the Marek Family is no longer part of canon.)

**Out of Universe:**

The *Rebels* version of the Starbird logo was designed by concept artist Chris Glen.

> "I'm probably most proud of the Rebels' phoenix logo. I made it one day on a whim while working on really early versions of the Ghost ship, and it's remained unchanged all the way through marketing. It's meant to hint at the Rebel Alliance symbol that will appear in the later films."
>   ―Chris Glenn, Star Wars Insider 154

Comment: It's also very reminiscent of the Jedi Crest, which predates Sabine's logo by... a lot.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a clear shot of it on an official item/screencap (at work right now, so I can't dig too much), but it's on Obi-Wan's armor during the Clone Wars.

Comment: http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25300000/Obi-wan-clone-wars-obi-wan-kenobi-25345290-640-480.png

Comment: [anakin has it on his armor too](http://www.firstshowing.net/img/clonewars-anakin2.jpg)

Comment: I'd be tempted to go with [this photo](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/4/49448/1549143-cwa_obi_wan_kenobi_6_psd_jpgcopy.jpg) or [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:BaneKenobi-Showdown.jpg) if you want an actual screen capture from the Clone Wars.

Comment: Good answer, but you may want to add that in the previous canon it was actually the house insignia of the Marek family, and was used to honor the sacrifice of Galen Marek (as seen in the The Force Unleashed).

Answer (score 27):

It is the crest of the Marek family. At the end of *The Force Unleashed* videogame,

> the Rebel Alliance adopts it after Galen Marek's sacrifice.

Comment: I'd add that the red starbird, being a phoenix, is a symbol of  renewal, resurrection etc. According to wikipedia, Princess Leia declared it a "symbol of hope".

Comment: The Force Unleashed is currently Legends, though, right?

Comment: @DavidBanner - does Wikipedia have a cite?

Comment: @DKN No, unfortunately it doesn't, but starwars.wikia provides a quote from the video game *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed*: "We need a flag to rally behind. A symbol. A symbol of hope." -- Leia Organa. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alliance_Starbird

Comment: @DavidBanner If you can track down the novelization, I think I remember that having more background as well.

Comment: @Plutor - legends schmegends.

Answer (score 4):

We now have canon confirmation of the origin of the Rebel Alliance symbol.

The Jedi on Jedha use a 'starbird' symbol that looks essentially identical to the Rebel logo. It notes that the Rebellion have recently adapted it for their own use.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>Rogue One: Visual Dictionary</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly, the new [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded) contradicts this slightly, stating that the logo is based on two elements; The three-pronged symbol favoured by Saw Gererra and the Starbird graffiti tag designed by Sabine Wren.

[image]

[image]

The starbird crest is itself, in turn, based on the historic symbol for the Jedi Order, seen in the "ancient books" that Rey liberates from the First Jedi Temple on Ahch-To.

> [image]

> **Production designer Rick Heinrichs spoke with story group executives
> Pablo Hidalgo and Leland Chee about the logo, figuring out how much
> leeway he had to come up with the various structures.**
>
> **"Is it okay to use the rebel icon symbol if you do it obliquely,
> hopefully not hitting it on the head too hard?** It's hard to know
> exactly how subtle you can be with this stuff," Heinrichs wrote. "It's
> an unfolding universe, and we want the audience to recognize it and be
> comfortable in it—for it to feel — but also to create something new
> that they haven't seen before."
>
> <sub><sup>['Star Wars: The Last Jedi' - the Rebel Logo Was Born out of the Ancient Jedi Text](https://comicbook.com/starwars/news/star-wars-the-last-jedi-rebel-logo-jexi-text/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

The trident-like top image shows a great resemblance to the symbol seen in a few Clone Wars episodes, for example on Saw Gerreras' shoulder.

[image]

He's going to be in Rogue One, which brings me to the conclusion that we might see him in Rebels as well. After all, Rebels is supposed to tie in to Rogue One at some point and what better way to do it than bringing back a freedom-fighter like Saw and **showing the origin of the Rebellion logo?**

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for your first contribution :) I'm a little unclear on how this answers the question. Are you saying the insignia developed from this symbol? Okay, do you have any confirmation of that? Why did that happen? What, in any case, does it represent? If you can support this answer, it could be really interesting. At the moment it feels more like a comment